# Can I connect to Counter Strike 1.6 using Counter Strike: GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Like the title states, can *Counter Strike: Global Offensive* connect to a Counter Strike 1.6 server?

All my friends are using Counter Strike 1.6, but unfortunately, 1.6 does not support my computer, but I am eager to play with my friends if this is possible?

Comment: What kind of computer supports CS:GO but not CS 1.6?

Comment: @3ventic Linux/Mac?

Comment: @Novarg According to the store pages, 1.6 is Win/Mac/Linux while GO is just Win/Mac

Answer (score 10):

There are four versions of Counter-Strike on Steam:

- [Counter-Strike 1.6](http://store.steampowered.com/app/10/)
- [Counter-Strike: Condition Zero](http://store.steampowered.com/app/80/)
- [Counter-Strike: Source](http://store.steampowered.com/app/240/)
- [Counter-Strike: Global Offensive](http://store.steampowered.com/app/730/)

Unfortunately, none of these games are compatible with each other. You will have to be playing the same version if you want to play with your friends.